# How to give all users on the system permission to run the iptables command without a password

Tags: permissions, sudo, group

So I thougt of `# visudo`

but then the thing is I don't want to create a group and then add all users to this group like the following.

```
%users ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/passwd
```

But is there a way to just reference all users without having to create a group first ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just replace `%users` with `ALL`:

```
ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/iptables
```